# update the value with string replace in postgres query

Tags: php, sql, postgresql

I have the table `user` and I want to replace the `username` field value from `'test user'` as `'Test User'`.

In update query for all `username` field values

```
update user set username='replace()'
```

Is it possible to do by query.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

use INITCAP

```
UPDATE user
SET username = INITCAP(username)
```